# exec bad adress, NULL addet

Tags: c, null, fork, exec

I try to use execvp and it worked fine, but now I chanced the way to declare the arguments and now I get "bad address" as error.
I red a lot of same problems and the problem was the NULL as last argument.

I tried a lot of ways to append the NUll on the end but it doesnt work.

```
char *args4exec[5];

 switch(argsi)
      {
        case 1:
          printf("case 1 arg\n" );
          strcpy(&args4exec[0],command);
          strcpy(&args4exec[1],args[i-1]);
          args4exec[2] = NULL;
          break;
        case 2:
          printf("case 2 args\n" );
          strcpy(&args4exec[0],command);
          strcpy(&args4exec[1],args[i-2]);strcpy(&args4exec[2],args[i-1]);
          strcpy(&args4exec[3], NULL);
          break;
      }
    }

    if (execvp( args4exec[0], args4exec) == -1 )
      perror("exec failed");
```

strcpy and normal defintion doesnt work, Can anyone help me?
The code I posted doesnt work but it should show the ways I tried to add the NULL.

Comment: this would be a good time to learn how to use `gdb` or the debugger of your choice!  You don't include enough information for us to answer you.  For example, do you initialize the strings you're trying to copy to with `strcpy` ?

Comment: Have you allocated memory for the elements of the array `args4exec`? Otherwise, you have undefined behaviours when copying with `strcpy`.

Comment: Have you printed `args4exec[0]` & `args4exec[1]`, does it prints as expected ? what is the `command` ? Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

before copy your `command` or another strings to `args4exec` you should allocate memory for it:

```
char *args4exec[5];
char *command = "Hello";
args4exec[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(command));
```

Also here is error in your `strcpy()` compiler should warn about it. Should be like this:

```
strcpy(args4exec[0], command);
```

if you use `gcc` compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

And you should check your `args[i - 2]` and other parameters to be sure that they store correct values and not out of bounds.